# Creating a calculated field using Datastudio RegEx_Contains

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I am trying to create a field having two values "Branded Query" & "Non-Branded Query" using RegEx_Contains().

[Column here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1daXI.png)

Any record which contains "at 60" should be categorized as Branded Query.

I have used the below formula but it's not working:

```
Case    
when REGEXP_CONTAINS(Query,"*.at60*.") then "Branded Query"
else "Non-Branded Query"
End
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 1):

. means anything, * means repeated any number of times, so you want .* and not *.